# Xpath to extract all the texts present inside all the div element

Tags: html, xpath

What is the XPATH I should use to extract only the inner text present in all the div elements.

Comment: What's the definition of *inner text*? Text that is a child of `div`? Or descendants? (includes text that's inside an `<a>`, which is inside a `<div>` as well) Attributes? And if many text nodes are returned, do you want them concatenated, an array? Please elaborate your question and add code examples showing an example of what you wish to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//div/descendant-or-self::*/text()
```

Expression gives all text in  does not matter how deep inside.